# How to make a character required in regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I wanted to do a simple validation of a phone number. A phone number should be 13 in length and should contain a `+` sign at the start. So, `+123456789001` is a valid number `1234566780111` is invalid.

I'm using this currently, but I am not sure how to make `+` a required character at the beginning.

```
/^[0-9]{13}+$/
```

In function:

```
function validate_mobile($mobile)
{
    return preg_match('/^[0-9]{13}+$/', $mobile);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original expression is just fine, we would just add a `+` to it:

```
$re = '/^\+[0-9]{12}$/m';
$str = '+123456789001';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wqpZWE/1/)

Then our function might look like:

```
function validate_mobile($mobile)
{
    return preg_match('/^\+[0-9]{12}$/m', $mobile);
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]